Does the "How to vote" pop-up on the election page disappear immediately for others too?
I have clicked over to the election page to vote, and I briefly see a browser modal dialog titled "How to vote" that disappears almost immediately before I have any interaction with the page.
I'm pretty sure I can figure out the voting procedure (not my first election, looks like there are instructions on the side), but it's kind of irritating, and my guess is that some first-time voters might be confused/discouraged.
(I'm on Windows + FireFox. I do have NoScript installed, but I think I've enabled almost all hosts that are used on StackExchange sites.)

Added 8/15/2024: Well, I've discovered that what I'm seeing is the pop-up that one normally gets when clicking on the "Learn more" link in the "Your ballot" section.
Why it's temporarily displayed on entering is beyond me, but this is an older, slower machine, and it sometimes takes a second or two for StackExchange pages to figure out just how they want to be displayed.

No pop-up of any kind appeared for me (Google Chrome + Windows)

Is this what you're looking for?.  It appears on the actual place to vote, as a link only. Or perhaps the problem you mention was corrected?  What browser to you use, @Jonathan ?

^ Afaict what amWhy refers to is the only thing, other than perhaps the "Learn more" in the "your ballot" gui

@amWhy - I wasn't looking for anything relating to "How to vote", it just popped up when I went to the page, and it only stayed for like a fraction of a second before disappearing. Anyways, I've now tried it on Windows+Chrome and Android+Firefox, and it doesn't show up on either of those, and it's not stopping me from voting, so should I close this question?
